# Unsatisfiable version constraints with androidTestImplementation Google Truth 1.0 and implementation Google Guava 27.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-guava, google-truth

### In short

I can't get a minimal and new **Android Studio** project to build with the following added dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0"
}
```

### How to reproduce

This is how I do it but there are also other ways of course.

1. In **Android Studio 3.5.2**:

   1. *File* → *New* → *New Project...*
2. In **Create New Poject** dialog:

   1. *Phone and Tablet* tab → *Add No Activity* → *Next*
   2. *Name*, *Package name*, *Save location*: **Whatever you want**
   3. *Language*: **Java**
   4. *Minimum API level*: **API 28**
   5. *This project will support instant apps*: **Disabled**
   6. *Finish*
3. In **./app/build.gradle**:

   1. Add `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'` and `androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0"` to  `dependencies`
4. In **ExampleInstrumentedTest.java**

   1. Right-click on `class ExampleInstrumentedTest` and select **Run 'ExampleInstrumentedTest'**

**Expected**
The test passes

**Actual**
Build error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:{strictly 2.5.2}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.5'
           Constraint path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:{strictly 2.5.2}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.5.2
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.2'

   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:{strictly 2.2.0}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1'
           Constraint path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:{strictly 2.2.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.2.0
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0'

   > Could not resolve org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.5.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.truth:truth:1.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.5'
           Constraint path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:{strictly 2.5.2}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.5.2
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.2'

   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.truth:truth:1.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1'
           Constraint path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:{strictly 2.2.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.2.0
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0'

   > Could not resolve org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.5'
           Constraint path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:{strictly 2.5.2}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.5.2
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.2'

   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1'
           Constraint path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:{strictly 2.2.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.2.0
           Dependency path 'sdfsf:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android' --> 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0'
```

How can I fix this build problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was embarrassingly simple. Just use `'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android'` instead of `'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'`.